# How I can be reusable design custom cells for other view controllers?

Tags: ios

I want to design a custom cell for the TableView but want to reuse the same cell for other view Controllers. Before .xib used files, my question is if they are the only option or you can do something like that with the Storyboard.

Comment: If you are using a UTableview cell inside storybord then it was accessible to the specific Tableview not overall App , but If you make Xib of cell can accessible anywhere in app.

Comment: It is recommended even XIB files?

Comment: Yes better you go with Xib if you wanna use custom cell in anywhere in app

Comment: Check out "Protocol and Value Oriented Programming in UIKit Apps" from #WWDC 2016 https://developer.apple.com/wwdc16/419. It is advanced topic how to share code of the cells and view controllers with minimum dependency of UIKit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can reuse custom cell for many tableviews creating "CustomCell" class.

To reuse custom cell you have to `#import"yourcustomcell"` in `viewcontroller` where ever you want.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

You can do it and can learn step by step from [custom table view cell](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/).